# how to print utf-8 in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, character-encoding

I am developing a web-site in jsp which is in a non English language(Persian). I have a string (*query*) in utf-8 which I want to print on page. I just know this command to do it:

```
out.print(query);
```

All other parts of my page are in utf-8 and are rendered correctly. But this variable is not renderable and it seems that the function *out.print* does not print it in a correct way.

PS: I printed query in a txt file and it was just correctly printed.

Comment: Can you do it in plain HTML?  If you achieve that, I bet you'll be 95% of the way to doing it in a JSP.

Comment: You don't use scriptlets in JSP!

Comment: At the top of the page set the char set header as UTF-8 via `response.setHeader('charset', 'UTF-8');`

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`out.print(new String(query.getBytes(),"UTF-8"))`. If you know the charset of the query string, use `java.lang.String.getBytes(Charset)`. Example,
 `out.print(new String(query.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8"))`